# what is integral of $\int(1/2)exp^{-|x|} dx $ for -m to m with m is real number

Tags: integration

i have some difficulty to finish this integral, can you show me how to find the result of this integration?

$$\int(1/2)e^{-|x|} dx  $$ for (-$m$ to $m$) whdere $m$ is a real number.

Comment: Write it as a sum of two integrals.  One from $-m$ to $0$, the other from $0$ to $m$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: This is an even function, so $$\int_{-m}^m\frac{1}{2}e^{|x|}dx=\int_{0}^me^{|x|}dx=\int_{0}^me^{x}dx$$

Comment: True, but I think my hint is more instructive.

Comment: @user42388 how it work? can u explain it to me?

Comment: Suppose $f(x)$ is an even function. Then $\int_{-m}^mf(x)dx=\int_{-m}^0f(x)dx+\int_{0}^mf(x)dx$ Now make a change of variables to the first integral $x->-x$. So you get $\int_{o}^mf(x)dx+\int_{0}^mf(x)dx=2\int_0^mf(x)dx$